# Pandas: Multiply a column based on a different columns condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python with Pandas. How can I multiply a column by 1000 given another column has a certain string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it.

```
df['columnname'] = np.where(df['othercolumn'] == 'CertainString',
                                           df['columnname'] * 1000,
                                           df['columnname'])
```

Comment: thnak very much this solve problem